# Efficient algorithm for finding a set of non adjacent subarrays maximizing their total sum

Tags: algorithm

I've come across this problem in a programming contest site and been trying different things for a few days but none of them seem to be efficient enough.

Here is the question: You are given a large array of integers and a number k. The goal is to divide the array into subarrays each containing no more than k elements, such that the sum of all the elements in all the sub arrays is maximal. Another condition is that none of these sub arrays can be adjacent to each other. In other words, we have to drop a few terms from the original array.

Its been bugging me for a while and would like to hear your perspective on approaching this problem.

Comment: Since "Arrays" usually means 2D when used generically, what does an array "with no more than k elements" mean? Or are these arrays really 1D like vectors or lists?

Comment: Yes these are lists in the one dimensional sense.

Comment: I've tried using a recursive sliding window approach which is reasonably fast for the general case (linear amortized) but is very slow for pre sorted arrays (quadratic).

Comment: Maybe greedy is the key here? Too lazy to code it.... What's the link to the problem, BTW?

Comment: Can array elements be negative?  Can subarrays be adjacent to either edge of the original array?

Comment: No they are all non negative, this could simplify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic programming should do the trick. Short explanation why:

The key property of a problem susceptible to dynamic programming is that the optimal solution to the problem (here: the whole array) can always be expressed as composition of two optimal solutions to subproblems (here: two subarrays.) Not every split needs to have this property - it is sufficient for one such split to exist for any optimal solution.

Clearly if you split the optimal solution between arrays (on an element that has been dropped), then the subsolutions are optimal within both subarrays.

The algorithm:

Try every element of the array in turn as the splitting element, looking for the one that yields the best result. Solve the problem recursively for both parts of the array (the recursion stops when the subarray is no longer than `k`). Memoize solutions to avoid exponential time (the recursion will obviously try the same subarray many times.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this approach won't find the correct answer if array elements can be negative.  e.g. let k = 3; then we shouldn't stop at a subarray of [1,-5,1]

Comment: @gcbenison True - of course you don't need to recurse anymore but you still need to find the optimal subarray within the one of length `k`. There is a linear algorithm for that but the combined complexity starts to look bad.

Comment: @gcbenison Eh, OP clarified there's no negative values there, this indeed simplifies the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but a clue.

Consider solving the following problem:

From an array X choose elements a subset of elements such that none of them are adjacent to each other and their sum is maximum.

Now, the above problem is a special case of your problem where K=1. Think how you can expand the solution to a general case. Let me know if you don't know how to solve the simpler case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to explain why this works and should be the accepted answer:

```
def maxK(a, k): 
    states = k+1
    myList = [0 for i in range(states)]
    for i in range(0, len(a)): 
        maxV = max (myList)
        myList = [a[i] + j for j in myList]
        myList[(states-i) % k] = maxV  
    return max(myList)
```

This works with negative numbers too. This is linear in `size(a)` times `k`. The language I used is Python because at this level it can be read as if it were pseudo code.